# What are idioms that are antonymous to "don't skimp on"?

Tags: idiom-request

The idiom "don't skimp on" means don't be shy and put as much as necessary. I am now wondering if there are idioms that mean the opposite of that. I am sure there are many, but it's hard to look for idioms since you can't look them up on a dictionary unless you know them.

For example:

> Please, don't skimp on the butter. It's good stuff!

Comment: You want the opposite of "give me lots of x", right?

Comment: @woken - We recommend waiting half a day or so before accepting an answer (see [_Not so fast!_](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer) on meta.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are unlikely to use the antonym in the imperative form. We don't tell people to "use less than is needed".

There are plenty of ways to describe someone using less of something

> He was scrimping (and saving)
>   He was being frugal
>   He was stingy
>   He was mean with the butter
>   He was being careful with the butter.

These have a different nuance.  Being "frugal" and "careful" are generally positive. Being mean or stingy are negative.

Answer (score 4):

You could say:
"Go easy on the ..."

"Light on the ..."

"Don't over-do it on ..."

"Be sparing with ..."

"Don't get carried away with the ..."

"Take it easy with the ..."

"Be judicious with ..."

"Use a light touch with the ..."

or even the simple, "Not too much ..."

Answer (score 1):

Please give me  [just adjectives] 
-  just a little butter.
- a tad of butter.
- just a dab of butter.
- just a teeny bit of butter.

Actual idioms:
Please **go light on** the butter. To go light on butter or cream or sugar. Anything you add to food or drink.

Please **don't overdo it** on the butter. [not too much, same as above]

Please hold off on the butter. [not any]